# Why Room.databaseBuilder function requires context as the parameter in a Room database?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-context, android-database

```
companion object {
        @Volatile
        private lateinit var instance: ExampleDatabase

        fun getInstance(context: Context): ExampleDatabase {
            synchronized(this) {
                if(!::instance.isInitialized) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,  // Why does this require context?
                        LottoDatabase::class.java,
                        "lotto_database"
                    )
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .build()
                }
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code is the general way of creating singleton of the room database.
I wonder why Room.databaseBuilder function requires a context as the parameter. I know this question might be stupid cuz I'm lack understanding of the Context in Android.

1. What argument should I pass in that parameter?
2. What can be different if I pass in the Activity context or application?

Answer (score 0):

The **Room.databaseBuilder()** function in Android is used to create an instance of the Room database. It requires a context as a parameter for a few reasons:

1. **To create a database instance.** Room uses the context to create a database instance in the application's database directory.
2. **To access the database file.** Room uses the context to access the database file, which is stored in the application's internal storage.
3. **To provide access to the database to other components.** Room uses the context to provide access to the database to other components of the application, such as the DAO and ViewModel classes.